# GoEthereum and Lighthouse syncing issue: CRIT Failed to update execution head

Tags: go-ethereum, lighthouse

I am running an Ethereum node using GoEthereum and Lighthouse.

For some reason, it has fallen off from the chain tip and does not properly sync anymore.

Lighthouse is reporting in its logs:

```
Jan 11 13:42:20.100 CRIT Failed to update execution head         error: ExecutionForkChoiceUpdateFailed(EngineError(Api { error: Reqwest(reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: Url { scheme: "http", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("example.com")), port: Some(8553), path: "/", query: None, fragment: None }, source: TimedOut }) })), service: beacon
```

GoEthereum is reporting API request failures with "Ignoring payload with missing parent".

```
WARN [01-11|13:49:41.440] Served eth_getLogs                       conn=172.18.0.2:33222 reqid=1                         duration=437.81056ms  err="failed to get logs for block #15395331 (0x3eabef..e8233b)"
WARN [01-11|13:49:50.548] Ignoring payload with missing parent     number=16,383,974 hash=06b53a..1c45bc parent=48702e..c2e382
WARN [01-11|13:50:00.029] Ignoring payload with missing parent     number=16,383,975 hash=a30530..cb3aa7 parent=06b53a..1c45bc
```

Because neither of applications is giving a clear indication of what could be the root cause of an error, I am asking here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears I had the same problem:  Error 'CRIT Failed to update execution head'  (Other related "Failed Called ... errors" ) started randomly appearing 30 hours ago; started with occasional missed assets, and progressively worsened.

After assesment I increase my ram 12-16GB. It >Appears<  this resolved it. I was running With (Average) 10GB of 12 GB of Ram occupied ; forced 5GB of 12GB of Swap-space to be used at all times. My assumption is this alone made my Besu/Lighthouse node unstable after only 10 days.

The reason for this assumption is with 16 GB of Ram installed now, My Swap-space is almost unused < 1GB on average . Suddenly my Node is performing much more consistently.

Good luck